# Array values coming out incorrectly in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio

I have been working at this for over 2 hours. I have isolated my problem to one piece of code.

The problem is with my array. It is outputting really big negative values. The values I am feeding into the array are correct. I am experienced with java, but this is my first C++ program.

```
   #include <cstdlib>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <sstream>
   #include <string>

   using namespace std;

   int main(){
    string inputString;
    cin >> inputString;
    cout << inputString << endl;

    int mainArray[10];

    for(int x = 0; x < inputString.length(); x++){
        int valFound = inputString[x]-48; //minus 48 to change from ascii to int
        mainArray[valFound]++;
        cout << mainArray[valFound];
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated, this is making me crazy.

Comment: `int mainArray[10] = {0};` Initialise the array.

Comment: Also, `inputString[x] - '0'` is more portable.

Comment: @DanielFisher or SamFrench please make an answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your array is being default initialized. Default initialization of the type `int` leaves it "with garbage". You need to initialize it to `0` explicitly:

```
int mainArray[10] = {0};
```

Comment: That works. I swear I tried that before, but I guess not.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This is because arrays need to be initialized. Add this to your code:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != 10 ; i++) {
    mainArray[i] = 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `memset`:

```
memset(mainArray, 0, sizeof(mainArray));
```

Comment: Traditional C! very nice always :)